# i get error when i use query firebase/firestore in react

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

i want to get data with query method from firebase firestore db

```
import { db } from './firebase';
import { collection, getDocs ,addDoc} from 'firebase/firestore/lite';
import { doc, setDoc, updateDoc ,query, orderBy, limit,where } from "firebase/firestore"; 
import { getFirestore } from 'firebase/firestore' 


export const getAllProjects = async () => {
    const projectsCol = collection(db, 'projects');
    const q = query(projectsCol,  where('caseStudy', '==', 'wrapped_Green') );
    // const q = query(projectsCol,  where('caseStudy', 'in', 'wrapped_Green') );
    const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => { console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data()); });
    
};
```

code stop in  `const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);` line

i can get all the data with this method :

```
export const getAllProjects = async () => {
    const projectsCol = collection(db, 'projects');
    const projectSnapshot = await getDocs(projectsCol);
    const projectlist = projectSnapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data());
    return projectlist;
}
```

and i try to add console.log() before any a line and all the console.log() work before   `const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);` line and stop after this

`console.log(q)` give me :

[image: q]

The code is inspired by Firebase dosc and I followed all their steps
Firebase version: `"firebase": "^10.8.0",`

@frank-van-puffelen
when i use only query  the output is
`size: 2 QuerySnapshot > {_docs: Array(2), query: _CollectionReference}`

```
export const getcaseStudy = async () => {
    const projectsCol = collection(db, 'projects');
        const q = query(projectsCol);
        const projectSnapshot = await getDocs(q);
        console.log('size:',projectSnapshot.size,projectSnapshot)
        const projectlist = projectSnapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data());
    return projectlist;
};
```

but when i use where with query there is no output

```
export const getcaseStudy = async () => {
    const projectsCol = collection(db, 'projects');
        const q = query(projectsCol,where("caseStudy",'==','wrapped_Green'));
        const projectSnapshot = await getDocs(q);
        console.log('size:',projectSnapshot.size,projectSnapshot)
        const projectlist = projectSnapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data());
    return projectlist;
};
```

Comment: What do you get when you `console.log(projectSnapshot.size)`? Please edit your question to show that updated code, and its output.

Comment: Logging `q` is not helpful because there are no query results in a query object.  You need to call getDocs in order to actually perform the query and get results returned. `querySnapshot` is the thing that actually contains resulting documents, if there are any.